# Is a package specific to a Linux distribution? How to protect against KRACK

Tags: linux, distributions, vulnerability

I run multiple distributions of Linux. I am researching how to patch against [KRACK](https://www.krackattacks.com/).

The package that is vulnerable in Linux is 'wpa_supplicant'.

According to the [Vendor Responses](https://github.com/kristate/krackinfo#vendor-response-complete) the "Linux patch" for wpa_supplicant can be found [here](https://w1.fi/security/2017-1/), whereas the (for example) Fedora patch can be found [here](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/wpa_supplicant-2.6-11.fc27) and the Debian patch can be found [here](https://www.debian.org/security/2017/dsa-3999).

**In which circumstances would/could I download and apply the so called "Linux patch" directly**? Is that only if I'm using the Linux Kernel directly? Otherwise, if I'm running on a specific distribution of Linux, do I need to wait for a patch from that specific distribution?

Note my question refers to a specific vulnerability (KRACK), but **I'm trying to understand generally, what is the difference between what the [project puts out](https://w1.fi/) (in this case the hostapd and wpa_supplicant project) versus what the different Linux distributions release.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is like *what do a distribution?*

Distribution adapt and integrate the packages in the overall distribution, e.g. PATH, manuals, init scripts, logs, cronjob, firewall, etc.  Additionally they configure the package to be used and integrated with specific other packages (which crypto library version, which random generator to use, etc.).  They adapt also default configuration file.

So there are many changes in the distribution binaries. Additionally there are tests.

The *upstream* provides the sources and functionalities, and you can take the original sources and compile yourself.  But than you need to understand (and read all original document on how to compile and how to install the program).  The **Linux patch** is to be applied on the original sources.

If you know some programming, you can download the sources of your distribution and apply the patch, and build and install the modified packages. Remember to modify the changelog or the build command, in order to have a local version suffix, so you see if you have the original or a patched version.

Open source has the strength to be able to use also such method. But I would not do it first the first time on important programs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all Linux distributions have own packages. And most of them provide some tool for automatic update (yum/dnf/apt). So when the distribution provider (company or community) fixes the issue, it should be available for update using the automatic update system mentioned before.